# Twilio - Unable to get client id while making call

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am getting an error "Unable to get Client ID" while initiating the call from Twilio API via JavaScript SDK.

Here is the PHP Code

```
$callerId = "+1xxxxxxxxxx";
            if (isset($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'])) {
                $number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber']);
            }
if (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $number)) {
            $numberOrClient = "<Number>" . $number . "</Number>";
        } else {
            $numberOrClient = "<Client>" . $number . "</Client>";
        }

$xml = '<Response>
                   <Dial callerId="'.$callerId.'">
                   '.$numberOrClient.'
                   </Dial>
                   <Record timeout="1000" transcribe="true" />
                </Response>';
```

Here is the error screenshot

[image]

Comment: In your TwiML you have `<Client></Client>`, so you're not setting a client identity. Can you share the code you are using to generate the TwiML?

Comment: I have updated the code in the main question.

Comment: Where is `$number` coming from in your code?

Comment: {{$number}} updated in a main thread.

Comment: From your other question, I believe you're using Twilio Client to place these calls. Are you sending a `PhoneNumber` parameter when you call on `Device.connect`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `$number` is an empty string when you call the function and this produces invalid TwiML.

According to the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client#), the `<Client>` tag needs to contain a string or several tags to specify the clientId.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Dial>
     <Client>
        <Identity>user_jane</Identity>
        <Parameter name="FirstName" value ="Jane"/>
        <Parameter name="LastName" value ="Doe" />
      </Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Client>joey</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```